# Double fragment rotating Android with ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-actionbar

I've made a simple Android Activity with an ActionBar to switch between 2 fragments.
It's all ok until I rotate the device. In facts, when I rotate I've got 2 fragment one over the other: the previous active one and the first one.
Why?
If the rotation destroy and recreate my activity, why I obtain 2 fragments?

Sample code:

**Activity**

```
package rb.rfrag.namespace;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class RFragActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Notice that setContentView() is not used, because we use the root
        // android.R.id.content as the container for each fragment

     // setup action bar for tabs
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Tab tab;
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.VarsTab)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<VarValues>(
                        this, "VarValues", VarValues.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.SecTab)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<SecFrag>(
                        this, "SecFrag", SecFrag.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

**TabListener**

```
package rb.rfrag.namespace;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;

public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {    
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've resolved using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` in the Activity to maintain the selected tab and modifying `onTabSelected` as follows.

The last modify avoids that Android rebuild the Fragment it doesn't destoy. However I don't understand why the Activity is destroyed by the rotation event while the current Fragment no. (Have you some idea about this?)

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // previous Fragment management
        Fragment prevFragment;
        FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
        prevFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(mTag); 
        if (prevFragment != null) { 
            mFragment = prevFragment; 
        } // \previous Fragment management

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Any clue as to if this is the "proper" way of doing things?

Comment: Until I found this, that drove me nuts... Thanks so much for this answer! (Still can't believe that Google would not fix that in their example)

Comment: Interesting. Only I use a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in portrait and display both fragments when landscape. Rotate twice and I get two fragments in landscape. One called something like *android:switcher:2131099773:1* — drives me nuts. I have to find a hock to get rid of the zombie.

Comment: After a lot of r and d this solved mah problem too :) thanx @asclepix

Comment: I don't understand this. onDestroy() is indeed called on the fragment when rotating the device. How can it still be used adn visible after that?

Comment: Works like a charm! Anybody know why the example from the official doc does not work? Are we all doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Since I use a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` overriding `onTabSelected` would not help. But still you hint pointed me in the right direction.

The `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` saves all fragments in the `onSaveInstanceState` of the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. **Ignoring  `setRetainInstance`** — Depending on your design this might lead to duplicate fragments.

The simplest solution is to delete the saved fragment in the `orCreate` of the activity:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate (final android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      if (savedInstanceState != null)
      {
         savedInstanceState.remove ("android:support:fragments");
      } // if

      super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
…
      return;
   } // onCreate
```

Comment: This worked well except that when Fragment2 goes into Landscape, fragment1 is displayed. Not sure if I'm the only one who has this problem. Any solution?

Comment: Works with your solution in portrait and landscape too. not overlapping anymore after switching between tabs.

Answer (score 3):

The solution does not actually require a whole lot of work, the following steps ensure, that when rotating the screen, the tab selection is maintained. I ran into overlapping Fragments, because upon screen rotation my first tab was selected, not the second one that was selected before rotating the screen and hence the first tab was overlapping the content of the second tab.

This is how your Activity should look (I am using ActionBarSherlock but adjusting it should be very easy):

```
public class TabHostActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

   private static final String SELETED_TAB_INDEX = "tabIndex";


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Setup the action bar
     ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

     // Create the Tabs you need and add them to the actionBar...

     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Select the tab that was selected before orientation change
        int index = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELETED_TAB_INDEX);
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(index);
     }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     // Save the index of the currently selected tab 
     outState.putInt(SELETED_TAB_INDEX, getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition());
   }
}
```

And this is what my  ActionBar.TabListener looks like (its a private class in the above Activity):

```
  private class MyTabsListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
     private Fragment fragment;
     private final SherlockFragmentActivity host;
     private final Class<Fragment> type;
     private String tag;

     public MyTabsListener(SherlockFragmentActivity parent, String tag, Class type) {
        this.host = parent;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.type = type;
     }

     @Override
     public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        /*
         * The fragment which has been added to this listener may have been
         * replaced (can be the case for lists when drilling down), but if the
         * tag has been retained, we should find the actual fragment that was
         * showing in this tab before the user switched to another.
         */
        Fragment currentlyShowing = host.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

        // Check if the fragment is already initialised
        if (currentlyShowing == null) {
          // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
          fragment = SherlockFragment.instantiate(host, type.getName());
          transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag);
        } else {
          // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
          transaction.attach(currentlyShowing);
        }
     }

     public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        /*
         * The fragment which has been added to this listener may have been
         * replaced (can be the case for lists when drilling down), but if the
         * tag has been retained, we should find the actual fragment that's
         * currently active.
         */
        Fragment currentlyShowing = host.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (currentlyShowing != null) {
          // Detach the fragment, another tab has been selected
          fragmentTransaction.detach(currentlyShowing);
        } else if (this.fragment != null) {
          fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
        }
     }

     public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // This tab is already selected
     }
```

The above implementation also allows replacement of Fragments within a tab, based on their tags. For this purpose when switching fragments within the same tab I use the same Tag name, that was used for the initial framework that's been added to the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin and asclepix for theirs solutions. I have 3 tabs and first tab contains 2 fragments, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frActiveTask"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frTaskList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/frActiveTask"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using `onRestoreInstanceState`, `onSaveInstanceState` and `savedInstanceState.remove("android:support:fragments");` methods and statement working almost fine except if your active tab is not the first one and rotate and click on first, a clear display appears and only for the second click on the first tab came the right fragment display.
After debugging code I recognized that the first `addTab` always calls an `onTabSelected` event in the tab listener, with a fragment `add` method and then when the `setSelectedNavigationItem` is called from `onRestoreInstanceState`  a `detach` is executed on the first tab and an `add` for other one.
This unecessary `add` calling is fixed in my solution.

My activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    boolean firstTabIsNotAdded = false;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedInstanceState.remove("android:support:fragments");
        firstTabIsNotAdded = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELETED_TAB_INDEX) != 0;
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// codes before adding tabs

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    tabStartAndStop = actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_title_start_and_stop))
            .setTabListener(
                    new FragmentTabListener<StartStopFragment>(this, 
                            getString(R.string.tab_title_start_and_stop_id), 
                            StartStopFragment.class,
                            firstTabIsNotAdded));
    tabHistory = actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_title_history))
            .setTabListener(
                    new FragmentTabListener<HistoryFragment>(this, 
                            getString(R.string.tab_title_history_id), 
                            HistoryFragment.class,
                            false));
    tabRiporting = actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_title_reporting))
            .setTabListener(
                    new FragmentTabListener<ReportingFragment>(this, 
                            getString(R.string.tab_title_reporting_id), 
                            ReportingFragment.class,
                            false));

    actionBar.addTab(tabStartAndStop);

        actionBar.addTab(tabHistory);
        actionBar.addTab(tabRiporting);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int index = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELETED_TAB_INDEX);
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(index);
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save the index of the currently selected tab
        outState.putInt(SELETED_TAB_INDEX, getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition());
    }
```

And the modified tab listener

```
public class FragmentTabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mFragmentActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private boolean doNotAdd;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public FragmentTabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, boolean doNotAdd) {
        mFragmentActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        this.doNotAdd = doNotAdd;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            if(doNotAdd){
                doNotAdd = false;
            }else{
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mFragmentActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            }
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```