# Fragments Not Working Correctly After Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having a problem with `Fragments` and orientation change.

I have an application which has a `MainActivity` which handles the switching up `Fragments` via a tabbed action bar. Here is the code for the tabbed action bar and when a tab is selected.

```
private class MyTabListener <T extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private android.support.v4.app.Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public MyTabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null){ // check to see if the fragment has already been initialised. If not create a new one.
            mFragment = android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content,mFragment,mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment); // if the fragment has been initialised attach it to the current activity
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null){
            ft.detach(mFragment); // when a fragment is no longer needed, detach it from the activity but dont destroy it
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
```

The way I see it is that everything works fine when the application first loads in portrait mode. When I rotate, for some reason another instance of `Fragment1` is added and then isn't detached when another tab is selected. This is also the case when I then rotate back to portrait.

I have tried using `setRetainInstance(true);` in my `Fragments` but this doesn't work.

Is there a method I need to override or do something with my `Fragments` before rotating?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I have now seen that onTabSelected is called again when the activity is recreated. Could this be the cause of my problem with fragments being attached more than once?

Here is my activities onCreate method.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
     // Create the Action Bar with tabs
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //create the tab for track and add it to the action bar.
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText("Track")
                            .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<TrackingFragment>(this,"track",TrackingFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        //create the tab for ski tracks and add it to the action bar.
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Something Tracks")
                        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<TrackListFragment>(this,"somethingtracks",TrackListFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        //create the tab for photos and add it to the action bar.
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Photos")
                        .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<PhotoFragment>(this,"photos",PhotoFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short fix:**

In the `onTabSelected` method, before using `if (mFragment == null)` you need to try to get the fragment (using `mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag)`). You can also set this from the outside but I don't see you doing this.

Checking `if(savedInstanceState == null)` on `onCreate` could also solve this and I consider it a better approach though! :)

Comment: If i put my action bar code in the onCreate method it doesn't get created or shown when the activity is recreated after an orientation change. I will try the supportManager part now

Comment: +1... sneaking in there with the right answer while I was editing.  :)

Comment: is the fragment not being passed in when it calls the setTabListener?

Comment: Well, look at the contructor.  ` public MyTabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz)`...   An activity, a tag and a class.  No fragment passed in there.

Comment: Thank you @Barak and Pedro you have both helped me a lot and if I could give you both the green tick I would. In the end it was just a case of getting the fragment from the manager and checking. Just like you guys said

Comment: No problem, Pedro came up with it first.  If my contributions helped you can upvote my answer without selecting it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you don't have something in your `onCreate` method wrapped in a `if(savedInstanceState == null)`, so you are creating another fragment in addition to the one being restored from the savedInstanceState bundle.

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at your code, I think I was wrong about the onCreate, your onTabSelected should handle it.  I think  your `if (mFragment == null)` is always coming up null, because you don't try and find the fragment.  Change that code section to:

```
@Override 
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) { 

    mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);   // add this

    if (mFragment == null){ // check to see if the fragment has already been initialised. If not create a new one. 
        mFragment = android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName()); 
        ft.add(android.R.id.content,mFragment,mTag); 
    } else { 
        ft.attach(mFragment); // if the fragment has been initialised attach it to the current activity 
    } 
}
```

Comment: are we talking in my fragment or my main activity?

Comment: I would hazard a guess your main activity.  Whatever sets you up and displays your initial view.

Comment: I have added my onCreate method to my question above

Comment: Updated my answer.  I think I was heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that `setRetainInstance` is actually ignored and all fragments created by the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` are stored in `onSaveInstanceState` and are recreated in `onCreate`.

For me the solution was to bluntly delete the superfluously saved fragment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996054/341091

Answer (score 1):

I had more or less the same problem, but the solutions presented above did not seem to work out in my situation. Eventually I found the following solution:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag); // Use replace iso add
    }
    else {
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if(savedInstanceState == null) is not working always. sometimes savedInstanceState != null while you need to add another fragment because of landscape orientation.

Another approach is to test whether fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayoutLeft), no matter what the orientation is, is null or not, if so, than create a new fragment instance otherwise do nothing. If you  need a second fragment in landscape mode, you need first check whether it's landscape or not if so, check whether fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayoutRight) is null or not. if null, than create, otherwise do nothing because it's already there retained by Android OS.